# React Native Navigation and state management

Tags: android, ios, react-native

React Navigation vs Routers(What should i use?)
Redux vs Redux ToolKit(What should is use?)

What should i use for navigation between screens Reac† navigations or routers, And for state management inside the application what should be useful redux or redux tool?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - the whole question is opinion based.. for navigation I would go with react navigation tho.